# How do I access Locale from a JSP?

Tags: jsp, struts, locale

I want to include a js file depending on the value of the current Locale. I have tried to access it from JSP as follows:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Locale" %>  
<% if( ((Locale) pageContext.getAttribute("org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE",PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE)).getLanguage().equals("de")) { %>
    <script src="../themes/administration/js/languages/i18nDE.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<% } else { %>
    <script src="../themes/administration/js/languages/i18nEN.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<% } %>
```

However, I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` because   `pageContext.getAttribute("org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE",PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE)` is `NULL`.

Does anyone knows how I can solve this?

Answer (score 20):

At the moment I am using this :

```
<c:set var="localeCode" value="${pageContext.response.locale}" />
```

This can later be access by using `${localeCode}`

1. **Scriplet mode**, discouraged! See [Why not use Scriptlets](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/WhyNotUseScriptlets) for reason not to use a scriptlet.

The `localeCode` variable can be queried inside a **scriptlet** with:

```
<%
  Object ob_localeCode = pageContext.getAttribute("localeCode");
  if (ob_localeCode != null) {
    String currentLanguageCode = (String) ob_localeCode;
  }
  //more code
%>
```

2. **Scripletless mode** correct way to go. See [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/112106) Here on SO.

I am using spring 2.5 config at the moment.

So following this, coming back to your original question you can implement something like:

```
<c:set var="localeCode" value="${pageContext.response.locale}" />
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="$localecode == 'de' }"> 
    <script src="../themes/administration/js/languages/i18nDE.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <script src="../themes/administration/js/languages/i18nEN.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

or if you really want to use some short code to impress your colleagues, you can do:

```
<c:set var="localeCode" value="${fn:toUpperCase(pageContext.response.locale)}" />
<c:set var="availLanguages" value="EN,DE" />
<c:if test="${!fn:contains(availLanguages,localeCode)}">
  <c:set var="localeCode" value="EN" />
</c:if>

<script src="../themes/administration/js/languages/i18n{$localeCode}.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

Comment: Agreed with @BalusC - one of the last two solutions should be the way to go. Don't go scriptlets... ever...

Comment: Do you happen to know why `pageContext.response.locale` would return null when the client is forwarded to a custom error page (403) following a `PUT` request?...For all other cases, this works ok.

Answer (score 6):

in  Struts2 try

```
<s:if test="#request.locale.language=='us'">
     <s:select name="gender" list="#{'M':'Male','F':'female'}" ></s:select>
 </s:if>
```

Answer (score 3):

Struts puts locale in the session. The correct way to get the Locale is:

```
Locale locale = (locale)request.getSession().getAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY);
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a constant `org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE` in the Struts 1.x documentation  - should it be [`org.apache.struts.Globals.LOCALE_KEY`](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts/Globals.html#LOCALE_KEY)?  Or one of the other `LOCALE_KEY` constants?

---

Edit:   `org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE` is the *value* of the `org.apache.struts.Global.LOCALE_KEY` - so the value itself, used as a key, shouldn't be the problem.

Verify that a `LOCALE` is being set in the `Request`.  My understanding is that the `LOCALE_KEY` is set in `PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE` if it is set.

Answer (score 1):

In Struts2, using EL I successfully used:

```
${sessionScope["org.apache.struts2.action.LOCALE"]}
```

E.g. to output the value of the Locale:

```
<c:out value='${sessionScope["org.apache.struts2.action.LOCALE"]}'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added new examples to clarify this a bit more because this post didn't help me much.

To get locale from jsp:

```
<%=request.getLocale()%>
```

it's a ServletRequest Method a Returns the preferred Locale that the client will accept content in, based on the Accept-Language header,

```
Struts2 Locale: <s:property value="#request.locale"/>
```

Returns the locale for the Struts2 Framework, that may or may not be the same as in the previous example. if you pass the param request_locale=de for instance...

```
<s:url id="localeDE" namespace="/">
   <s:param name="request_locale" >de</s:param>
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{localeDE}" >German</s:a>
```

the struts2 #request.locale will changed to german overriding the value of the original Accept-Language header

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
<s:if test='locale.toString() == "si"'>
    <script src="../themes/administration/js/languages/i18nDE.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</s:if>
<s:elseif test='locale.toString() == "ta"'>
    <script src="../themes/administration/js/languages/i18nEN.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</s:elseif>
<s:else>
    ANOTHER SCRIPT
</s:else>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ken G. pointed to the answer.

```
pageContext.getAttribute("org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE",PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE)
```

should be used instead

```
pageContext.getAttribute("org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE",PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@page import="java.util.Locale"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.struts.Globals"%>


<%Locale locale = (Locale)session.getAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY);
if (locale.getLanguage().equals("fr")) {%>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="lib/js/dateofday.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/lib/js/jscalendar-1.0/lang/calendar-fr.js"></script>
<%} else {%>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="lib/js/dateofday-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/lib/js/jscalendar-1.0/lang/calendar-en.js"></script>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The two best ways to get `locale` is by using the `getLocale` of Action support inherited by an action, onto a JSP:
`<s:hidden name="locale"/>` or
`<s:property value"%{locale}"/>`

When locale has been changed with [this method](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/how-do-we-change-locales.html).

It is not the same as:
`${pageContext.response.locale}`